# Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, jks

I am supplied with a jks keystore named ABCC_client.store. When I import this keystore to cacerts and try connecting it says No such Algorithm error. PFA the stacktrace

```
    Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class:   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1245)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:220)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:147)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:125)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:68)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.initFactory(JSSESocketFactory.java:61)
    at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:79)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
    at sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(KeyProtector.java:311)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:121)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:38)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:763)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.&lt;init&gt;(SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java:113)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(KeyManagerFactoryImpl.java:48)
    at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(KeyManagerFactory.java:239)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl.getDefaultKeyManager(DefaultSSLContextImpl.java:170)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl.&lt;init&gt;(DefaultSSLContextImpl.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1221)
    ... 39 more
```

But if I use this keystore independently i.e without adding it to cacerts it works.

Some googling led to me to http://joewlarson.com/blog/2009/03/25/java-ssl-use-the-same-password-for-keystore-and-key/ which says that password might me different for the key and the keystore.

Comment: A bit of code to see what's called if possible?

Comment: i was trying to call a web service method from within the code..AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)

Comment: May be duplicated here is a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321557/can-not-get-key-from-keystore) with an asnwer.

Comment: No My issue is the keystore works if we set the system properties to use that keystore. But If we load that keystore into jvm's default i.e cacerts it doest wrk. It says bad certificate..

Comment: in my case i was provided a wrong password.

Answer (score 137):

If using Tomcat 6 and earlier, make sure the keystore password and the key password are same. If using Tomcat 7 and later, make sure they are the same or that the key password is specified in the `server.xml` file.

Comment: This is true. Reference https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Prepare_the_Certificate_Keystore

Comment: Relevant quote: Finally, you will be prompted for the *key password*, which is the password specifically for this Certificate (as opposed to any other Certificates stored in the same keystore file). You **MUST** use the same password here as was used for the keystore password itself. This is a restriction of the Tomcat implementation. (Currently, the `keytool` prompt will tell you that pressing the ENTER key does this for you automatically.)

Comment: I had this issue w JMeter (https) coz Java keystore and key passwords were different. Ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889238/keystore-change-passwords?noredirect=1&lq=1 . to change the key password to solve the issue. Great help! Thanks.

Comment: @CaptainMan that's only true in Tomcat6, from Tomcat7 [it is not](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Prepare_the_Certificate_Keystore).

Comment: @AndreaLigios good point, relevant quote: Finally, you will be prompted for the *key password*, which is the password specifically for this Certificate (as opposed to any other Certificates stored in the same keystore file). The `keytool` prompt will tell you that pressing the ENTER key automatically uses the same password for the key as the keystore. You are free to use the same password or to select a custom one. **If you select a different password to the keystore password, you will also need to specify the custom password in the `server.xml` configuration file.**

Comment: Still an issue in Tomcat 8

Comment: Same for Jetty.

Answer (score 81):

The private key password defined in your app/config is incorrect. First try verifying the the private key password by changing to another one as follows:

```
keytool -keypasswd -new changeit -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -alias someapp -keypass password
```

The above example changes the password from password to changeit. This command will succeed if the private key password was password.

Comment: While I didn't use this answer in relation to the question. It was helpful for validating a keystore file, store password, alias/key, and key password.

Comment: Please remember that after executing this command you will change the keystore password. You would have to set the password back to the original one.

Comment: actually, it's enough to specify just `-keypasswd -keystore storefile -alias somealias` and enter everything else in a prompt.

Comment: On running this code I am getting the following error - `"keytool error: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key"` Is there any way to check what is my alias key password or change it without knowing the old one?

Answer (score 10):

In order to not have the `Cannot recover key` exception, I had to apply the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files to the installation of Java that was running my application. Version 8 of those files can be found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) or the latest version should be listed on [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads). The download includes a file that explains how to apply the policy files.

---

Since [JDK 8u151](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u151-relnotes-3850493.html) it isn't necessary to add policy files. Instead the JCE jurisdiction policy files are controlled by a Security property called `crypto.policy`. Setting that to `unlimited` with allow unlimited cryptography to be used by the JDK. As the release notes linked to above state, it can be set by [`Security.setProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Security.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) or via the `java.security` file. The `java.security` file could also be appended to by adding `-Djava.security.properties=my_security.properties` to the command to start the program as detailed [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-override-java-security).

---

Since [JDK 8u161](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u161-relnotes-4021379.html) unlimited cryptography is enabled by default.

Comment: I am seeing this error despite having the policy file jars installed.

Comment: @Adam My solution is for a specific case, which may be different to the one you are experiencing. However I've added an update to reflect the change that occurred in JDK 8u151.

Answer (score 6):

Check if password you are using is correct one by running below command

```
keytool -keypasswd -new temp123 -keystore awsdemo-keystore.jks -storepass temp123 -alias movie-service -keypass changeit
```

If you are getting below error then your password is wrong

```
keytool error: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
```

Comment: If I use any other password I receive error `Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`. If I use password I know its correct I get error `Cannot recover key`. So I don't think your statement is correct, at least in my case. Something else might cause the error

Comment: Tomcat can cause this issue when the keyAlias parameter is missing or the value is not matches the alias name in the keystore. Ensure you're using the correct alias by issuing `keytool -list -keystore something.jks -storepass temp123` and checking the alias in the listing.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error when we imported a key into a keystore that was build using a 64bit OpenSSL Version. When we followed the same procedure to import the key into a keystore that was build using a 32 bit OpenSSL version everything went fine.

Comment: The root cause of the Error above was java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key. The reason for that can be a false password as mentioned above, but also a keystore build with a 64bit OpenSSL Implementation. So I consider my Answer as another possible solution. It helped me in the same error situation, so I provided the solution here.

Comment: openssl doesn't create Java keystore files. Could you clarify this?

Comment: Thks for you answer. I face the same problem when invoking https webservices form OpenESB 3.05. I follow your instructions and generate the jks file again with a 32bit implementation of OpenSS and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this seems to be happening for no reason. I too faced the same and tried all methods like Keytool explorer etc.

Ultimately ended requesting Google to reset the key since I had Google play signing enabled. This is a good recommendation to follow.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en