# How to establish mTLS connection?

Tags: ssl, java-8, mtls

I have to make an mTLS connection so that my application can connected to an organization server. For that I am provided a CA root certificate (that I am going to store in my java cacerts) and a public and private key files (.pem) and  I am converting them into p12 keystore using openssl as follows:

openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey private-key.pem -in cert.pem -out test.p12 -name "aliaspk" -legacy

then I am converting the test.p12 keystore into my java 1.8 keystore using java keytool as follows:

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore test.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -srcalias aliaspk -destalias aliaspk

Now using privatekeyalias, clientkeyalias and passphrase and the keystore path I have to establish mTLS connection.

I am using the following method to establish an mTLS connection:

```
public class App {

    public void makeMTLSConnection(String url) {
          String passphrase = "password"; //that is used as destpass while make keystore.jks
         String certAlias  = "certalias";
         String privateKeyAlias = "aliaspk" //used as src and dst alias in the above cmd
     
         try(FileInputStream fis = "path/to/keystore/keystore.jks") {
            //Load Keystore
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            keyStore.load(fis, passphrase.toCharArray());

            // Get certificate by alias
            X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(privateKeyAlias);
            PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(privateKeyAlias, passphrase.toCharArray());

            //Add private key and certificate chain into the keystore
            keyStore.setKeyEntry(privateKeyAlias, privateKey, passphrase.toCharArray(), new Certificate[]{certificate});
            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, passphrase.toCharArray());
            KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();

        
        // Load the default java cacerts
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

            try (FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream("/usr/java/bin/lib/cacerts")) {
                trustStore.load(fis2, "changeit".toCharArray());
            }
            trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
            TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);

        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
         HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());

            conn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

            setTimeoutInConnection(60000);
            
              conn.connect();
        
    } catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But when I run the application to establish the mTLS connection I am getting the following error:

Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key at sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(KeyProtector.java:315) at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:143) at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:57) at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineGetKey(KeyStoreDelegator.java:96) at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:71) at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1023) at sun.security.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.<init (SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java:145) at sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(KeyManagerFactoryImpl.java:70) at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(KeyManagerFactory.java:256)
at
org.john.doe.Connector.makeMTLSConnection(Connector.java:224)... 49 common frames omitted

Comment: Have you tried the answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967650/caused-by-java-security-unrecoverablekeyexception-cannot-recover-key ?

Comment: A full exception stacktrace would help.

Comment: Thanks @BoppreH, I had different password for my keystore and privatekey. By making both equal it fix the above error but now I am getting following error:
 Extended key usage does not permit use for TLS server authentication