# trusted certificate entries are not password-protected java

Tags: java, keystore, saml-2.0

I have a .cer file provided from some other party. I need to create a saml credential with this .cer file.

For this, I imported .cer file to jks file using following command. ( Password is same as password. It asked from prompt to accept certificate. I gave y then it said certificate is added to keystore )

**keytool -importcert -file xyz.cer -keystore test.jks -alias "testsp"**

Then I used this jks file to create credential as below.

```
    private Credential getCredential() {
          KeyStore keystore = readKeystoreFromFile("C:\\Users\\WTC\\Downloads\\icicistage\\test.jks", "password");
          Map<String, String> passwordMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
          passwordMap.put("testsp", "password");
          KeyStoreCredentialResolver resolver = new KeyStoreCredentialResolver(keystore, passwordMap);

          Criteria criteria = new EntityIDCriteria("testsp");
          CriteriaSet criteriaSet = new CriteriaSet(criteria);

          Credential credential = null;
          try {
             credential = resolver.resolveSingle(criteriaSet);
          } catch (SecurityException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
         return credential;
    }

    private static KeyStore readKeystoreFromFile(String pathToKeyStore, String keyStorePassword) {
        try {
            KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(pathToKeyStore);
            keystore.load(inputStream, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
            inputStream.close();
            return keystore;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Something went wrong reading keystore", e);
        }
    }
```

The below line gives me the following error in try block.

credential = resolver.resolveSingle(criteriaSet);

**java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: trusted certificate entries are not password-protected**

Can anyone please guide me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue.

We no need to give the password in the password map. Since certificate contains only public key. It wont take the password.

Removed the below line from code and it works fine.

```
           passwordMap.put("testsp", "password");
```